# Replacing whole milk with sweetened condensed milk for cheescake

Tags: substitutions, milk, cheesecake

I am making a no bake cheesecake. It calls for milk but I just ran out. Can I substitute with sweetened condensed milk?

Comment: I use powdered whole milk, where I could control the thickness. I use Nestle Nido found in Walmart's hispanic foods section, rather than the flaky stuff that comes in a paper carton,as it gives a more authentic milky taste. Whereas, the flaky stuff tastes like detergent. A $13.88 can would make me an equiv of 10 gallons of fresh milk. With the economic crunch, more non-hispanics are using this to replace fresh milk that it disappears of the shelves fast.

Answer (score 3):

Sweetened condensed milk is approximately 40% sugar, so you would need not quite double the sweetened condensed milk, and you would have to deduct the additional sugar from the recipe.

You would need to multiply the amount of milk by about 1.7 to get the amount of sweetened condensed milk, and then deduct 40% of that (by weight) from the sugar in your recipe (you can assume that sugar is  7 ounces to the cup).

The thing is, sweetened condensed milk may have a cooked down taste, so you may not get the same pure creamy flavor that you would from fresh milk.

If you have additional cream or half and half in excess of what is called from in the recipe,while it may make the cake somewhat richer, you may have a better outcome using that in lieu of the milk.  You also will not have to adjust the sugar if you go that route.

Answer (score 3):

Many no bake cheesecake recipes call for sweetened condensed milk. May I suggest finding one of those instead of attempting a substitution?

Answer (score 2):

Sweetened condensed milk (SCM) is a milk reduction. If you add water to it (1:1 ratio) it can then be used as a replacement for whole milk.

Keep in mind that it has close to half a cup of sugar added per cup of SCM so if you are mixing it with water for a recipe you should reduce the sugar you add by 1/4 cup per cup of milk needed.

Answer (score -1):

I tried to use the percentages (almost doubling the condensed milk and reducing the sugar) for no-bake cocoa/oatmeal cookies. They came out okay--they held together and tasted good. I could have reduced the sugar even further.